# Run project on physical device. Linux drivers for Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, ubuntu, samsung-mobile

I have a Samsung Galaxy On8 (SM-J710FN) and I want test my applications created in Android Studio. I want to use my phone for this purpose. If I try to do it directly my phone is not shown. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit.

Comment: It should just work. What is `adb devices` showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the manufacturer drivers for your phone.

After that, when you plug it and the computer detects it, the phone should show a screen asking you to allow USB debugging for that particular computer, you should tap 'Ok'.

e: [Samsung drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows)

Comment: How can i install drivers tell me

Comment: Well, extract the file from the .zip, double click it and follow the instructions i guess. EDIT: sorry, i just saw you're on Ubuntu. I guess is time to google it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link below and **then enable USB debugging** from the options.
If you already did it . then the issue can be different.
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1053579